# My dll cannot load an assembly reference for system

Tags: c#, visual-studio, asp.net-core, dll, .net-framework-version

I have the following error when I try to use my dll library: 'Could not load type 'System.Web.TraceContext' from assembly 'System.Web, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.'

Some things to note:

1. The Library is written in .Net Framework 4.5
2. I am using .Net Core 3.1
3. I have access to the Library and we are using: Microsoft.Windows.Compatibility" version="6.0.0-rc.1.21451.13" targetFramework="net45" to make it compatible
4. I've noticed there are multiple versions on System.Web (2.0 AND 4.0) and others in the same vein

I had hoped to do as little as possible with the library since it is coming from another provider in my network.

Comment: Did you mean that you meet the issue when install the nuget package? Did you try other version?

Comment: Yes, but we need the package to have the 4.5dll work with 3.1Core. We are using a Core framework for the first time with this Library.

Comment: As you said that this package is [applied for .net framework](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.tracecontext?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to) but not net core.

Comment: For asp.net core, you may refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/logging-tracing)?

Comment: Yep, it just doesn't work in CORE, appreciate the help!

Comment: Thanks for your response and I've summed our chat below, could you pls accept it as the answer to make it easier for some others met similar issue to find it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To sum up here, `System.Web.TraceContext` is a library applied for .net framework, this [official document section](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.tracecontext?view=netframework-4.8#applies-to) showed it.

And in .net core for diagnosis tracing, we may use .net core [logging and tracing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/diagnostics/logging-tracing).